# facebook debugger og:image size error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am having the problem of facebook choosing the wrong thumbnail when I share my site. After doing research on fixes for this problem and attempting several solutions, facebook's debugger still insists that my og:image is smaller than 200x200 px when it is in-fact 400x400 px.

Unfortunately we are using a CMS that does not support actual implementation of Open Graph meta-tags due to the fact that users cannot edit the  code of their sites, but facebook does seem to pick up on my intended og:image when I use this alternative:

```
<link rel="image_src" href="http://payload122.cargocollective.com/1/8/259546/4759078/dodo_o.jpg" />
```

Actual error:

> Provided og:image is not big enough. Please use an image that's at least 200x200 px. Image 'http://payload122.cargocollective.com/1/8/259546/4759078/VabiannaSantos_905.jpg' will be used instead.

I've exhausted every solution I came across, from removing the image EXIF data to having the image be exactly 200x200 px.

Does anyone have a solution for me? If only Cargo Collective supported the implementation of Open Graph.

**site url**: http://dodoeditions.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The debugger error is a bit misleading, i guess it says "image is not big enough" when it should actually say "there is no og:image" - and it took another image instead. That one is 728x466 and should be big enough.

Put it on facebook, works quite fine for me, but you have to publish it to see how it will really look like. If you just put in the link, it will only show a small thumbnail and you can select one of 3 images.

So, in that case i would not worry too much about the error message, because it works perfectly fine. Much better would be og:tags, of course. If you are ever able to use them in your CMS, this page explains everything you need to know about them: http://ogp.me/

Additional info about the og:image tag:

- Recommended Size: 1200x630px, minimum 600x315px
- Recommended Ratio: 1.91:1

Comment: What browser are you using? I tried to share the image again and it still chooses the images that I do not want to display.

Comment: Firefox, but it should not matter

Comment: So when you try to share the site, this image is chosen as your thumbnail? http://payload122.cargocollective.com/1/8/259546/4759078/dodo_o.jpg

Comment: no, that one only shows up in the debugger, but not when i try to share the link on facebook

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need to change the name of your image so facebook actually refreshes it's cache and uploads your new image to it's servers, otherwise it ignores new images if they're saved under the same file name and doesn't pick up on them in the debugger - so you get errors like this